# Python eMail Maibox - Read any "Received" keys

Tags: python

I'm developing a script that allows me to read the "Received" field from the header of a file .mbox.

This is a small part of the code:

```
mbox = mailbox.mbox(filename)
print message.keys()
print message["Received"]
```

The print of the Keys takes me this result:

```
['Return-Path', 'Delivered-To', 'Received', 'Delivered-To', 'Received', 'X-Received', 'Received', 'Received-SPF', 'Authentication-Results', 'DKIM-Signature', 'Received', 'To', 'From', 'Subject', 'Message-ID', 'Disposition-Notification-To', 'Date', 'User-Agent', 'MIME-Version', 'Content-Type', 'Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'X-AntiAbuse', 'X-AntiAbuse', 'X-AntiAbuse', 'X-AntiAbuse', 'X-AntiAbuse', 'X-Get-Message-Sender-Via', 'X-Authenticated-Sender', 'X-Source', 'X-Source-Args', 'X-Source-Dir', 'X-getmail-retrieved-from-mailbox', 'X-GMAIL-THRID', 'X-GMAIL-MSGID']
```

From this I see that there are 3 fields "Received", but if I execute:

```
print message["Received"]
```

It only displays the first field, how do I print/view them all?

Thanks
Andrea

Answer (score 1):

When you call `__get__` it will linear scan the list of msg headers and return the first one with matching name.
To get multiple use `items()` method ie:

```
print [v for k, v in message.items() if k == "Received"]
```